# I want to import design library in androidx 29 version(latest version)

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, material-components, material-components-android

Below image clarify my question. I was try multiples of times to import design library in android studio lastest version 29 (android x) but library does'nt work kindly tell me the design library for androidx 29.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use : -

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' library in androidx for design.

Comment: The answer You **can not** use 
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` library in androidx for design, is simply **wrong**. You **have to use** it!

Answer (score 1):

The library `androidx.design:design:1.0.0` **doesn't exist**.
You have to use the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

> Material Components for Android is a drop-in replacement for Android's Design Support Library.

Add one of these in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'  //beta
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'  //stable
```

Comment: i want to use design library in this, any design library exists or not?

Comment: @HaiderShah The Material Components library **is** the new official design library: *Material Components for Android is a drop-in replacement for Android's Design Support Library*.