# My Target SDK version is 29 and MinSdk version is 15. Help me to provide the fit firebaseUI dependency

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am unable to provide the matching firebaseui in gradle file when i put the dependency of firebaseui it is giving error eg merger file etc

1.build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.smartcommittee"

        minSdkVersion 15

        targetSdkVersion 29

        versionCode 1

        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'

    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.0.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: Check the Peter answer. Also consider that you can't use androidx and support together and ['com.android.support:design:29.0.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538697/i-want-to-import-design-library-in-androidx-29-versionlatest-version/58538769?r=SearchResults&s=6|79.5547#58538769) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following dependency:

```
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.1.0'
```

Since you are using `androidx` dependency then update the firebase dependencies to the following, because you cannot mix old android depedencies with `androidx`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
```

You can check the following links for more information:

**How to migrate to androidx:**

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

**FirebaseUI and firebase release notes:**

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: it still not working giving merger error(ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0] C:\Users\Farman Ullah\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7c78a11c6b4a4456334831db0797030d\firebase-auth-19.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,

Comment: Increase project minsdk to 16

Comment: minSdkVersion 16

Answer (score 0):

You can change the your configuration 
from

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ShareIt"
        minSdkVersion 15 //here you got error
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

to

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ShareIt"
        minSdkVersion 16 //change 15 to 16, it is compatible with all dependencies
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

It works ;-)